# Jolt - Self containing Object- Resursively replace field name

Tags: java, json, jolt

I am pretty new to Jolt. I have a JSON payload that represents a logical condition such as AND/OR which can contain an array of conditions called "conditionPredicates". This can result in nested conditions of the form AND(OR(a, b ,c), OR(d,e)) I want to replace the field **`"conditionPredicates"`** as simply **`"conditions"`**. Any help please?

**Sample Input:**

```json
{
  "type": "Condition.Aggregate.AND",
  "payload": {
    "conditionPredicates": [
      {
        "type": "Condition.Apple",
        "payload": {
          "fruit": "apple"
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "Condition.Aggregate.AND",
        "payload": {
          "conditionPredicates": [
            {
              "type": "Condition.Orange",
              "payload": {
                "fruit": "orange"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**Expected Output**

```json
{
  "type": "Condition.Aggregate.AND",
  "payload": {
    "conditions": [
      {
        "type": "Condition.Apple",
        "payload": {
          "fruit": "apple"
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "Condition.Aggregate.AND",
        "payload": {
          "conditions": [
            {
              "type": "Condition.Orange",
              "payload": {
                "fruit": "orange"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a **shift** transformation like this one :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "payload": {
        "conditionPredicates": {
          "*": {
            "*": "&3.conditions[&1].&",
            "payload": {
              "*": "&4.conditions[&2].&1.&",
              "conditionPredicates": {
                "*": {
                  "@": "&3.conditions[&4].&3.conditions[]"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response. But my json payload can have unknown depth. EX: AND(a, AND(b, OR(c, ...)))

Comment: Hi @Aravind , unfortunately Jolt is not as much dynamic as we need.

Comment: Got it. Thanks so much for taking the time to answer.